# CodeIgniter: Multiple Applications, how to share resources?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dry, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to build a multi-app site using CodeIgniter. The individual applications need to be able to share model methods, helpers, libraries, etc. The documentation on CI's site (see: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Multiple_Applications/) seems to assume that resources do not need to be shared between the applications.

Does anyone know what I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I would recommend for specifically the resources you listed, is utilizing an application "package" path at the same level as your application folders.

[Go to the Application Packages section](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html)

just set your package path to "../common" or whatever you want at the same level as your applications.

Then That is a common place all your applications will look for these resources.